# How to know from which number a missed call came, if the caller has multiple numbers?

Tags: ios, caller-id, phone.app

In iOS 8.4.1, if a caller who has 6 numbers, calls you and you see a missed call. Then, clicking the "i" symbol next to the missed call showed you all the 6 numbers of the caller and the number from which he called, was indicated with blue. This helped in knowing exactly what number he called me from and I could call back *on the same number*.

iOS 9.0.1 call log does not indicate the number the caller called from with blue (if the caller has more than one number). So, it becomes impossible to call the person back on the same number.

This was one very important feature that made iOS 8 very useful. Apple has taken away a very important feature.

Comment: When I tap the little `i` in a missed call, it opens the contact page and the number from which he called you is shown in red (not in blue), but this is true for only some of my missed calls, not all of them. Maybe this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

#### Seems like a bug introduced in IOS 9

To me this seems like a bug introduced in IOS 9 that should get fixed automatically in future.

For outgoing calls, it continues to highlight in blue the specific number among multiple numbers in the contact on pressing `ⓘ` in the recent contact list.

For missed calls, it has stopped highlighting in blue but it still continues to show the `label` (like iPhone, mobile etc. ) for the missed call number on the main screen having all `recent` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The specific 'sub-contact' shows directly beneath the contact's name in the call history; same whether you answered it or missed it.

Even if your contact has several numbers in the same category [some of my company contacts have several 'mobile' tags] the phone knows which one of those called.

Simply tapping the caller in the list will dial that number, which is far quicker than the old method of finding the correct one in another list, accessed by the ⓘ button.

Screen shot shows a call from a contact's "mobile" number:
[image: iOS 9 recent calls screen]

Comment: What happen if you have the mobile tag for multiple numbers for the contact?

Comment: @Edenshaw - pretty sure I already covered that...

Comment: What if I want to copy-paste number somewhere if there are, e.g. multiple "mobile" tags?

Comment: then you'd need more descriptive tagging